# Python function that returns the value at index 0?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lambda

Does the Python standard library have a function that returns the value at index 0? In other words:

```
zeroth = lambda x: x[0]
```

I need to use this in a higher-order function like `map()`. I ask because I believe it's clearer to use a reusable function rather than define a custom one - for example:

```
pairs = [(0,1), (5,3), ...]

xcoords = map(funclib.zeroth, pairs)  # Reusable
vs.
xcoords = map(lambda p: p[0], pairs)  # Custom

xcoords = [0, 5, ...]  # (or iterable)
```

I also ask because Haskell does have such a function [Data.List.head](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:head), which is useful as an argument to higher-order functions:

```
head :: [a] -> a
head (x:xs) = x
head xs = xs !! 0

xcoords = (map head) pairs
```

Comment: Never ask for a library, it is off topic. I have edited the erring regions. Take care next time.

Comment: What is wrong with asking for a function in a language's own standard library?

Comment: I'm going to edit this question a bit more to reflect my original intent.

Comment: For the record, there was nothing wrong with the way that the original question was phrased. Showing the code that's currently being used and asking if there's an idiomatic approach using tools in the standard library is completely fine.

Comment: I am now confused so I asked a question regarding this on meta. Thanks @Nayuki for helping me clear my confusion.

Comment: Link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312954/are-standard-library-function-requests-on-topic

Comment: Note that the use of `head` is discouraged in Haskell because it is a partial function (and you don't get useful error messages when you try to run it against an empty list). Pattern matching or the use of `headMay` (in the Safe library) is preferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

```
>>> import operator
>>> pairs = [(0,1), (5,3)]
>>> xcoords = map(operator.itemgetter(0), pairs)
>>> xcoords
[0, 5]
```

In Python3, `map` returns a map object, hence you need a `list` call over it.

```
>>> list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), pairs))
[0, 5]
```

Comment: Perfect answer in 1 minute. I'll accept it as soon as the 15-minute timer expires.

Comment: `list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), pairs))` for python3

Comment: FWIW, I find `lambda p: p[0]` clearer than `operator.itemgetter(0)`

Comment: @Ned Is it because it is more readable or is there any other reason?

Comment: @BhargavRao,  itemgetter is faster than a lambda so it is definitely not  for performance

Comment: Just more readable to me. itemgetter is a function returning a function, which is more complicated than we need here.  Just my opinion, though.

Answer (score 3):

The most Pythonic approach would probably to use [`operator.itemgetter(0)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter). It returns just such a function.

Another approach would be to call [`obj.__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) directly. It's less Pythonic because it explicitly calls special method names, instead of allowing Python to infer what to call internally.

Comment: I understand `operator.itemgetter()`, but how does the second answer `obj.__getitem__` help with the problem?

Comment: @NayukiMinase because it's a function and not just pure syntax, you can manipulate it as a higher order function to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

With a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> pairs = [(0,1), (5,3)]
>>> xcoords = [ t[0] for t in pairs ]
>>> xcoords
```

Comment: This answer basically regurgitates the problem I have.